# Compile DLL written in C99 that works out of the box on most versions of Windows

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2015, runtime, c99

I've written a simple shared library using C99, and I'd like to port it to Windows. My aim is to provide a compiled DLL, so that it can be used in applications built using various old versions of Visual Studio (and C# via p/invoke).

I've managed to compile it as a DLL using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

However, I've got feedback that it only works on my machine, and won't load on others, because it depends on VCRUNTIME140.DLL, which is not part of Windows.

From what I've found the official solution is to tell users to go to microsoft.com, download and run an installer for VS redistributable package. To me it sounds like a really awful user experience. Is that *really* the solution?

How can I build a DLL that:

- uses C99,
- is compatible—out of the box with no extra installers—with Windows 7 and up,
- and can be loaded by applications built using Visual Studio 2008 and newer?

Answer (score 0):

> can be loaded by applications built using Visual Studio 2008 and newer?

This is the key to your answer. You must compile using Visual Studio 2008.

Binaries compiled with older tools can be used by newer tools, but it doesn't work backwards.

Comment: That does not answer my question, because VS2008 can't compile C99.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. That makes your problem more complex.

You may have luck trying to statically link against vcruntime, so that you don't need to distribute a second binary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Alternatively, you could look into other C compilers such as Pelles C.